# can you call on the same variable in an instance of multiple movieclips

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

It might sound confusing so let me explain the situation. I made a movieClip. And in that movieClip I have a dynamic textfield set. I called this textfield  "AmmoCount"

I dragged this movieClip onto the stage several times and each time I called on the AmmoCount variable in each movieclip and gave it a different value. I get the following error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Below is my code

```
trace(game.score.wH.weapon1.AmmoCount.text);
trace(game.score.wH.weapon2.AmmoCount.text);
```

When I trace these objects, weapon1.AmmoCount works, but weapon2.AmmoCount shows as empty. Yet they both contain a value in them.

Ive used the weapon1 property and weapon2 property countless times and there is no doubt that it works. so why doesnt it work for weapon2. but for weapon1. Below is some code that I called on earlier that shows they work

```
game.score.wH.weapon1.alpha = 1;
game.score.wH.weapon2.alpha = .2;
```

these worked! but when I called on the AmmoCount text box within them, I get the error. The following image you can find within the weapon1 movieClip

[image]

Comment: It's hard to figure this out without seeing the code. That error is basically saying that the item you're trying to access doesn't exist. My first instinct is that the item may not be on the timeline when you're doing the trace(). Are you using timeline keyframes to display the weapon movieclips?

Answer (score 1):

NEVERMIND,the reason it didnt work was because I created the textbox in the first frame but not in all the frames. each frame shows a different image. I change the frames but the textbox doesnt exist. had to create instance for each frame.